# netbeans display/println a row of mySQL data that affect by min function

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, phpmyadmin, min

im using Netbeans IDE 8.0.2.

This is my example table in phpMyAdmin :

```
COMPANYNAME          CONTRACTNAME        CONTRACTDATE       PRICEOFCONTRACT
A                    REPAIR              2015 August 1       $100,00
B                    NEW TOOL            2015 December 13    $250,00
C                    COMPLAINING         2015 August 2       $0
```

this is my script

```
try {
    String sql = "select min(CONTRACTDATE) from mysecrettable";
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs = pst.executeQuery();

    if(rs.next()) {
        InputStream stream = rs.getBinaryStream(1);

        String add1 = rs.getString("min(CONTRACTDATE)");
        System.out.println(add1); 
    }
```

i have found a date of CONTRACTDATE that is the minimum value. So the minimum value from the table is 2015 August 1.

i need script to display all data that stick in row of the minimum value of CONTRACTDATE, 
which is :

```
A, REPAIR, 2015 August 1, $100,00
```

Sorry for my bad English, im beginner in using JAVA and phpMyAdmin :-), many thanks in advance

Comment: What are you doing with the InputStream?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels : i dunno know sir, im using a tutorial that expalined about max and min phpMyAdmin

Comment: I think you need to go back to some basic SQL - `select * from mysecrettable where CONTRACTDATE  = (select min(CONTRACTDATE) from mysecrettable)` or some such...and then have a look at [JDBC Database Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) for more details about how to manage that from within Java

Comment: @MadProgrammer: hmm,  but how to display data in row of that minimum value? i think your answer is only show another way to find minimum value of Contractdate right? (sorry when im wrong, im beginner sir)

Comment: No, my comment is showing you how to ask the database to return all the columns in the table `mysecrettable` whose `CONTRACTDATE` is equal to the `min(CONTRACTDATE)` (and `=` might need to be `in`, but I don't have anything against which to test against).  Then you use the `ResultSet` to retrieve the individual values, as demonstrated in [Retrieving and Modifying Values from Result Sets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer: hmm,sorry i get confused sir, would you please write the script for me?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to learn some basic SQL, `select min(CONTRACTDATE) from mysecrettable` is only going to return the min value for `CONTRACTDATE` (`2015-08-01`), not the other columns.

Basically, you need to ask the database to "select the following columns matching the following criteria", something like...

```
select * from mysecrettable where CONTRACTDATE in (select min(CONTRACTDATE) from mysecrettable)
```

Which will return ALL the columns in the table `mysecrettable` where the `CONTRACTDATE` matches any of the results from the query `select min(CONTRACTDATE) from mysecrettable`

A good place to start might be the [w3shchool's SQL Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/)

Once you have that, you need process the possible results

```
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url)) {

    try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from mysecrettable where CONTRACTDATE in (select min(CONTRACTDATE) from mysecrettable)")) {

        try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {

            System.out.printf("%-20s | %-20s | %-10s | %s%n",
                            "Company Name",
                            "Contract Name",
                            "Date",
                            "Price");
            while (rs.next()) {

                String companyName = rs.getString("COMPANYNAME");
                String contractName = rs.getString("CONTRACTNAME");
                java.sql.Date contractDate = rs.getDate("CONTRACTDATE");
                long priceOfContract = rs.getLong("PRICEOFCONTRACT");

                System.out.printf("%-20s | %-20s | %-10s | %s%n",
                                companyName,
                                contractName,
                                new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(contractDate),
                                NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(priceOfContract));

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Which will print something like...

```
Company Name         | Contract Name        | Date       | Price
A                    | Repair               | 01/08/2015 | $10,000.00
```

Which is covered in much more detail in [JDBC Database Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/)

Comment: wow, so many things that i haven't learned about SQL thing, what is the function of "%-20s | %-20s | %-10s | %s%n" ? But many thanks for the advance sir @MadProgrammer. i would try that.

Comment: It's `String` formatter, you see this a lot in C/C++ where they don't have a concept of `String` like Java does